# How to access fastify app instance inside an imported file

Tags: javascript, node.js, fastify

Im working on a fastify powered rest api and im trying to separate my code into logical files. I have some class objects that i import into my server where fastify is defined and the fastify.listen happens. What i cant figure out is how to access the fastify instance inside a file that i import.

app.js

```
import fastify from 'fastify'
import autoload from 'fastify-autoload'
import { join } from 'desm'

export default function (opts) {
  const app = fastify(opts)

  app.register(autoload, {
    dir: join(import.meta.url, 'routes')
  })

  return app
}
```

```
server.js

import createApp from './app.js'
import 'dotenv/config.js'
import Sessions from './scripts/sessions.js'

import emitter from 'central-event'
async function start () {
  const app = createApp({ logger: true })

  await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, process.env.IP || '0.0.0.0')
  const intervalSeconds = process.env.intervalSeconds * 1000
  setInterval(function () {
    emitter.emit('heartbeat')
  }, intervalSeconds)
}

start()
```

I want to access the fastify app instance inside sessions.js that is imported into server.js I have tried various things like importing fastify and creating the app in there hoping that it would be inherited etc. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why Sessions is not used in any way?

Comment: That wasnt the question i asked, why isnt important. My point was how do i access/pass it into an imported file, so that i could.

Answer (score 1):

I found the info i needed. Inside the imports for sessions and others im exporting the class via export default (app) => class Sessions{}

then inside server i import it:
import SessionsImp from './scripts/sessions.js'

then pass the app via:
const SessionsClass = SessionsImp(app)
const Sessions = new SessionsClass()

It seems convoluted but it works as i wish, then i can decorate app with the sessions and other classes im loading and use them inside routes and plugins as i wish.